# Update state on a separate widget flutter

Tags: flutter, state-management

I am trying to figure out how to update the state of a widget when I press a button.

Here are a couple screenshots to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

When I hot reload the app the update takes effect but the state does not update when I press the update button on the dialog box.

I know there are handful of techniques to get this to work but I haven't been able to get it to update by passing a function through the constructor.

I also can't quite figure out how to use provider.of(context) without passing it some value. There is no value that is used in both places (the mainDebt widget and the allDebts widget).

The home page code is pretty simple. A stateless widget that holds the different widgets that I need displayed:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              HpHeader(),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              QuoteBox(),
              SizedBox(height: 30),  
       
              MainDebtDebt(),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              AdCard(),

              AllDebtsCard(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Enter Debt'),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/enterDebt1')),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              AdCard(),
              //etc........
```

The mainDebtDebt is the widget that I need to update state. It is reading data from SharedPreferences that is set when I press the update button on the dialog box:

```
import 'dart:async';

//import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:debt_zero_2/classes/icon_class.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MainDebtDebt extends StatefulWidget {

  
  @override
  _MainDebtDebtState createState() => _MainDebtDebtState();
}

class _MainDebtDebtState extends State<MainDebtDebt> {
   
   bool thenum = true;

  static DebtModel debtIcons = DebtModel();
  bool getGoalType = true;
  double balance = 0.0;
  String name = '';
  String type = ''; 
  int numOfDebts = 0;
  double safetyBalance = 0.0;

  double mainSnowballOpeningBalance = 0.0;

 

  Future<void> getGoalTypeFlag() async {
    final SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final sortBy = preferences.getInt('sortBySnowOrAva');
    setState(() {
       if (sortBy == 1){
      balance = preferences.getDouble('mainDebtFieldSnowball');
      type = preferences.getString('mainDebtFieldSnowballType');
      name = preferences.getString('mainDebtFieldSnowballName');}

       if (sortBy == 2){
      balance = preferences.getDouble('mainAvalancheBalance');
      type = preferences.getString('mainAvalancheBalanceType');
      name = preferences.getString('mainAvalancheBalanceName');
       }

      mainSnowballOpeningBalance = preferences.getDouble('openingBalance');  

      safetyBalance = preferences.getDouble('safetyBalance');
      getGoalType = preferences.getBool('mainGoalIsDebts');
      numOfDebts = preferences.getInt('numberOfDebts');     
    
    });
  }



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getGoalTypeFlag();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(getGoalType
              ? 'I\'m Knocking Out This Payment:'
              : 'I\'m Building My Safety Fund'),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                getGoalType
                    ? debtIcons.getDebtIcon(type)
                    : '',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Text(getGoalType ? name : 'Safety Fund'),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(getGoalType ? 'Remaining Balance:' : 'Saved:'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 15,
              ),
              Text(getGoalType
                  ? '\$' + balance.toStringAsFixed(0)
                  : safetyBalance.toStringAsFixed(0))
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Current Progress:'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                height: 22,
                width: 202,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Flexible(
                      child: FractionallySizedBox(
                        widthFactor: .75,
                        //fix this
                        // 1 - mainSnowballBalance / mainSnowballOpeningBalance,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text(getGoalType ? 'MAKE A PAYMENT' : 'MAKE A DEPOSIT'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/makePayment');
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('GET DATA'),
                onPressed: ()async {
                 
                  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                      

                    String thenum = pref.getString('debtId');
                    //pref.setBool('isInOb', null);
                    print(thenum);
                  
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The sort dialog is currently in the AllDebtsCard. It currently works to sort the list by either the highest interest or lowest balance respectively:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:debt_zero_2/classes/min_debt_class.dart';
//import 'package:debt_zero_2/classes/icon_class.dart';
import 'package:debt_zero_2/widgets/provider_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AllDebtsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AllDebtsCardState createState() => _AllDebtsCardState();
}

class _AllDebtsCardState extends State<AllDebtsCard> {
  int debtValue = 1;

  int group;

  void setValues() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getUidPref();
    final db = Firestore.instance;
    setState(() {
      sharedPrefs.setInt('sortBySnowOrAva', debtValue);
      SetMainDebt().setMainDebt();
    });

    db
        .collection('userPreferences')
        .document(uid)
        .updateData({'sortBySnowOrAva': debtValue});
  }

  getValues() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int intValue = sharedPrefs.getInt('sortBySnowOrAva');

    return intValue;
  }

  restore() async {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      group = (sharedPrefs.getInt('sortBySnowOrAva') ?? false);
    });
  }

  final dbPath = Firestore.instance.collection('userDebts');

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> dbStream(BuildContext context) async* {
    final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getUidPref();
    final intValues = await getValues();
    yield* intValues == 1
        ? dbPath
            .document(uid)
            .collection('debts')
            .orderBy('balance')
            .snapshots()
        : dbPath
            .document(uid)
            .collection('debts')
            .orderBy('interest', descending: true)
            .snapshots();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    restore();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('SORT'),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, setState) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('Sort Debts By:'),
                        content: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RadioListTile(
                              value: 1,
                              secondary: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          title: Text('Debt Snowball:'),
                                          content: Text(
                                              'This is an explanation of debt snowball'),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            FlatButton(
                                              child: Text('OK'),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                              },
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      });
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
                              ),
                              title: Text('Snowball'),
                              groupValue: group,
                              onChanged: (T) {
                                setState(() {
                                  group = T;
                                  debtValue = 1;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            RadioListTile(
                              value: 2,
                              title: Text('Avalanche'),
                              secondary: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline),
                              ),
                              groupValue: group,
                              onChanged: (T) {
                                setState(() {
                                  group = T;
                                  debtValue = 2;
                                });
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        actions: <Widget>[
                          FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              setState(() {
                                setValues();
                              });
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: Text('UPDATE'),
                          ),
                          FlatButton(
                            child: Text(
                              'CANCEL',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }).then((value) => setState(() {}));
          },
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: dbStream(context),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final debts = snapshot.data.documents;
                List<Widget> debtWidgets = [];
                for (var debt in debts) {
                  final debtName = debt.data['name'];
                  final debtType = debt.data['type'];
                  final debtBalance = debt.data['balance'];
                  final debtDue = debt.data['due'].toDate();

                  final debtWidget = Card(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('$debtType'),
                        Text('$debtName'),
                        Text(DateFormat.MMMd().format(debtDue)),
                        Text('$debtBalance'),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'DELETE',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            //When I delete a debt I need to update the 'debtMinimum' field in prefs and firestore
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );

                  debtWidgets.add(debtWidget);
                }
                return Column(children: debtWidgets);
              }
              return Container();
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am not opposed to trying any technique that works. Lifting state up, provider, or anything else(that wouldn't necessatate an entire rebuild of the architecture(which I know isn't anything close to great)).
I've been trying for days to figure this out. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the widget to update with StreamBuilder and than send event to stream sink when RaisedButton pressed. Below simple example:

```dart
/// Some where in State class
class _SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> {
  /// Stream controller which takes integer identifiers
  StreamController<int> streamController;

  /// Result stream which converts int to UpdatableObject via function
  Stream<UpdatableObject> get stream => streamController.stream.asyncMap(_getObjectById);

  /// Takes object identifier and returns corresponding object.
  Future<UpdatableObject> _getObjectById(int id) {
    ...
    return UpdatableObject();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Take from parent `Provider` widget
    streamController = Provider.of<int>(context, listen: false);
    // or create it here (depends on requirements)
    //streamController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<UpdatableObject>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString();
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        // `snapshot.data` contains instance of `UpdatableObject`
        return TheWidgetToBeUpdated(data: snapshot.data); 
      }
    );
  }
}
```